# Record Video and Audio and upload to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, webrtc

I want to integrate functionality in website to record video and audio through webcam and headset and upload to the server so that it can play later on. Currently we have tried with `WebRTC` but its not working in `IE` browser. Now I need to find the solution so it should work in all the browser.

- We are also thinking If any reliable solution not found then create browser extension to record video and upload that to server like `WebX` doing.

Please let me know If any one know the existing proper solution or `Javascript` libraries to record video or the approach to do the same. If any demo or example will be good start on the same.

Comment: Ohh come on ! any one would has done video recording in `IE`

Comment: [Pipe](https://addpipe.com/) and [HDFVR](https://hdfvr.com/) work on IE.